# I can't format text in th edit page (or posts) whats wrong..?

Tags: posts

Well like it says - I edit a Page, I want to use bold or italics, or colours.
Or I want to add a break so that text appears on different lines, but whatever I do - when I save the page and view it Alla the formatting is gone and the text all appears on the same line.

If I click the 'visual' tab it looks just as I'd like it, but not when I view the web site.

Would a style sheet override my formatting..?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Tony.

Comment: When switching from visual to html you need to save before the switch. Both are in the same place, but don't know anything about each other.

Comment: apart from @kaiser's comment it can also be a stylesheet issue

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that could cause the issue, or I should say a combination of things. With the formatting problems, you might have the "**!important css**" declaration overriding your CSS from the page/post editor.

Here is an example:

```
.post {
      font-family:Verdana, sans-serif;
      font-size:14px !important;
}
```

> *Or I want to add a break so that text
>   appears on different lines*

This could be a few issues, the best way to correct it is to use [the plug-in TinyMce Advanced](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/)

Install the plugin, then go to Appearance>TinyMce, in the options that appear towards the bottom of the screen select the check-box that says Stop removing p tags. You can also check the box that says import editor style. If your theme has a specific file for the editor it will be used, if not it will try to emulate the css of your theme automatically.

**See the image for the TinyMce Settings:**
[image: TinyMce Advanced Settings Screenshot]